# Why does %f act like ~%n in my wine launcher?

Tags: launcher

I'm using Nemo as my FM and have a launcher that opens an image with MSPaint...

I have the `Exec` line set up as `wine "program_directory/mspaint.exe" %f`, but when I R-click say `Z:/media/1TB/image.png` and open with MS Paint, I get an error saying `Z:/home/user/image.png was not found.`

what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix??

Answer (score 0):

I got completely fed up with trying and just moved everything to a shell script...

I got the same issue there, so I did a `cd` command to the image directory before running mspaint.exe to fix it.